# Why my control's properties won't change outside its class?

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

I'm new in C# but not new to coding --being doing it for almost two decades--, and have a problem with properties in a custom control I'm building, which inherits from a Panel. When I put my properties, I can see them in the Designer properties list and can even set them, but when running my little application, it seems these properties values are not used. The same if I change a property programatically: no error but my control does nothing, it is like they are not properly set. However, if I do it programatically whithin the class, they do work. My guess is that something in my properties set/get stuff is not right. Please see the following code chunk of how I'm doing it:

```
public class ColorStrip : Panel
{
    // properties
    // ------------------------------------------
    // size of color clusters (boxes)
    private int _clusterSize = 20;
    // controls if show the buttons panel
    private Boolean _showButtons;

    // property setters/getters
    // ------------------------------------------
    // clusterSize...
    public int clusterSize
    {
        get { return _clusterSize; }
        set { _clusterSize = value; }
    }
    // showButtons...
    public Boolean showButtons
    {
        get { return _showButtons; }
        set { Console.Write(_showButtons); _showButtons = value; }
    }
    ....
```

So in my form, for instance in the load or even in a click event somewhere, if I put colorStrip1.showButtons = false; or colorStrip1.showButtons = true; whatever (colorStrip1 would be the instance name after placing the control in the form in design mode)... console.write says always 'false'; Even if I set it in the design properties list as 'true' it will not reflect the settled value, even if I default it to true, it will never change externally. Any ideas? Non of the methods get the new and externally settled property value neither, obviously the getter/setter thing is not working. Seems to me I'm not doing right the way I set or get my properties **outside** the class. It works only inside it, as a charm...Any help...very appreciate!

Cheers

lithium

p.s. TO CLARIFY SOLUTION:

Setting the property in this case *didn't work because I was trying to use a new set value within the constructor*, which seems can't get the new values since it is, well, building the thing. If I *change the property value* in Design mode > Property editor or in code externally to the object, say in it's parent form's load event, *it will change it but readable for all methods except the constructor,* of course :)

Comment: Are there multiple threads getting and setting the properties? Can you give us the test code?

Comment: Keep in mind that you're writing out the *old* value of `_showButtons` - if you do two sets in a row, do you see the new value?

Comment: Note that properties in .NET *should* be named using pascal-casing, that is, the first letter should be uppercase.

Comment: Guys --and girls if any-- thank you for writing back. I found the problem: if I try to access my properties within the constructor they won't have the values put externally nor using the Design property editor and I guess why: the object is not ready at that point. Oh, silly me! If I try to access the properties in any other method then it works. Thank you everyone! --and thanks god I took a nap!--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely an issue of the order of execution. Your property setter just sets a variable, but doesn't actually trigger anything on the control to update the state related to this variable (e.g. adding or showing the buttons I assume).

When you set the property befre the rest of the initialization is done, the value is being used, otherwise it isn't because during the initial go the default value is still the property value.

You need to act on the setter, here's some pseudocode to illustrate:

```
set {
  _showButtons = value;
  if (alreadyInitialized) {
    UpdateButtons();
  }
}
```

Note: make sure to first set the value, then act - otherwise you end up using the old value (just like your `Console.Write()` is doing).

Comment: Well I haven't go further implementing anything with this property but only read it in the constructor and in a function the constructor calls: it should load up a txt file with the color codes and start adding color clusters --colored panels-- but the starting left should be different if showButtons is true or false --if true, the starting left for the color clusters should be say 100 pixels, if false it should be 0

Comment: Yes! it was indeed an execution order....I found the problem: if I try to access my properties within the constructor they won't have the values put externally nor using the Design property editor and I guess why: the object is not ready at that point. Oh, silly me! If I try to access the properties in any other method then it works. Thank you everyone! --and thanks god I took a nap!--

Answer (score 0):

The quoted code doesn't look problematic. Are you sure you're referencing the same instance of ColorStrip? Also, check your .Designer.cs file to ensure that the code setting the property is there.

In fact, try simplifying your code by using auto-implementing properties:

```
public int clusterSize { get;set;}
public Boolean showButtons {get;set;}

public ColorStrip() { ... clusterSize = 20; ... }
```